# Javascript String Includes Exact Match without further matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

still learning JS and came across this issue that I was not fully sure how to approach so hopefully someone can help lead me in the direction. I have an array of product images each containing an `alt` string with the color referenced somewhere in it like this

```js
let images = [
  {id:1, alt:"A Red Jacket"},
  {id:2, alt:"A Red Heather Jacket"},
  {id:3, alt:"Picture of Red Heather Awesome Jacket"} 
]
```

I also have an array of all possible colors (which I am not currently using in my logic) but have it available:

```js
let colorOptions = ["Red", "Red Heather", "Blue", "Soft Red"]
```

I'm trying to check for each image in the `images` array if the `alt` text includes a given color, then create a color entry in that object with the given color.

ie. if `"A Red Heather Jacket"` string contains an instance of `"Red Heather"` then create a `color: "Red Heather"` entry in that object.

**Where I am at**

I have a working function where I am looping through the images array and using **.includes()** to check if there is a match in the alt string. It works for when the possible match color is two words (ie. `"Red Heather"`) and matches those two words in the string, but when I use something like `"Red"` then it will match `"Red"` AND `"Red Heather"`. Im trying to figure out if there is any way I could get "Red" to just match "Red" and not other instances where red is mentioned in the longer color?

Below is the function that works for a possible match `"Red Heather"` but doesn't for "Red"

```js
let images = [
  { id: 1, alt: "A Red Jacket" },
  { id: 2, alt: "A Red Heather Jacket" },
  { id: 3, alt: "A Red Heather Awesome Jacket" }
];

//not using the below array but think it could help
let colorOptions = ["Red", "Red Heather", "Blue"];

function findMatch(array, match) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].alt.includes(match)) {
      array[i].color = match;
    }
  }

  return array;
}

let redHeather = findMatch(images, "Red");
console.log(redHeather);
```

**Returns**

```
[
  { id: 1, alt: "A Red Jacket" , color: "Red" },
  { id: 2, alt: "A Red Heather Jacket", color: "Red" },
  { id: 3, alt: "A Red Heather Awesome Jacket", color: "Red" }
]
```

**Expected Result for** `findMatch(images, "Red")`

```
[
  { id: 1, alt: "A Red Jacket" , color: "Red" },
  { id: 2, alt: "A Red Heather Jacket" },
  { id: 3, alt: "A Red Heather Awesome Jacket" }
]
```

Let me know if there are some other ways to approach this, I have thought of breaking it up into an array or using **match()** with regex but unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also have an array of all possible colors (which I am not currently using in my logic) but have it available:

I think that's the problem. If some of the items there are substrings of other items, and you'd want *only* the other item to match if it exists in the input, then you need to include a check that the color you're looking for is the only one that exists in the input. Use `.every` to check that for every item in `colorOptions`, it's either the `match` argument, or it's not included in the `alt`:

```js
let images = [
  { id: 1, alt: "A Red Jacket" },
  { id: 2, alt: "A Red Heather Jacket" },
  { id: 3, alt: "A Red Heather Awesome Jacket" }
];

let colorOptions = ["Red", "Red Heather", "Blue"];

function findMatch(array, match) {
  for (const item of array) {
    if (
      item.alt.includes(match) && 
      colorOptions.every(color => color === match || !item.alt.includes(color))
    ) {
      item.color = match;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

let redHeather = findMatch(images, "Red");
console.log(redHeather);
```

If, like you mentioned, you want to use a regex, remove the `match` index in the array, then pass to `new RegExp`:

```js
let images = [
  { id: 1, alt: "A Red Jacket" },
  { id: 2, alt: "A Red Heather Jacket" },
  { id: 3, alt: "A Red Heather Awesome Jacket" }
];

let colorOptions = ["Red", "Red Heather", "Blue"];

function findMatch(array, match) {
  const index = colorOptions.indexOf(match);
  const newArr = colorOptions.slice(0, index).concat(colorOptions.slice(index + 1));
  const pattern = new RegExp(newArr.join('|'));
  for (const item of array) {
    if (item.alt.includes(match) && !pattern.test(item.alt)) {
      item.color = match;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

let redHeather = findMatch(images, "Red");
console.log(redHeather);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, that works and helps my use case/learnings a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do like:

```js
const images = [
  { id: 1, alt: "A Red Jacket" },
  { id: 2, alt: "A Red Heather Jacket" },
  { id: 3, alt: "A Red Heather Awesome Jacket" }
];
function JacketMatcher(array){ // I now prefer constructors over classes since you can have private variables where you don't have to write `this.` on properties you don't want public anyways
  this.match = match=>{
    const a = array.slice(), rx = new RegExp('^A\\s+'+match+'\\s+Jacket$');
    for(let i=0,o,v,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
      o = {}; v = a[i]; 
      for(let k in v){
        o[k] = v[k];
      }
      if(o.alt.match(rx))o.color = match;
      a[i] = o;
    }
    return a;
  }
  
}
const jm = new JacketMatcher(images);
const justRed = jm.match('Red');
console.log(justRed);
const redHeather = jm.match('Red Heather');
console.log(redHeather);
```